# Adding video using Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to add a youtube video in my site using Sencha. I use the following code:

```
 var pnl = new Ext.Panel({
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype:'video',
                url: "space.mp4",
                loop: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                poster: 'Screenshot.png'
            }],
            fullscreen: true
        })
```

Here I replace the `space.mp4` with a youtube url but it doesn't work. If I write `html:'you tube link'`, it works on the browser on my system, but not on iPhone.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Anish, did you manage to get this fixed? I'm having the same issue since upgrading from Sencha v0.95 (working) to v0.97 (not working)?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to embed the video with the embed code (iframe) provided by youtube. Just give your component the html attribute with the iframe code, e.g.:

```
html: '<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1VcZ5eOwHQA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```